# Is gcp https load-balancer Frontend can listen on port other than 443?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to listen on HTTPS - SSL on port other than 443, I don't see any way to do it.
the reason I don't use TCP load balancing is that the load balancer listen on SSL and the backend listen on HTTP (works great on AWS).
any idea?
[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason in why you would want to do this? Port 443 is a pretty standard listening port for HTTPS connections.

Comment: Yes, historical reasons. it is an API entry-point and I'm moving from AWS

Comment: I would recommend to move this question to Serverfault.- Have you try changing the field Port for the one you need?

Comment: I did try, nothing there. only 443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment, constraint is listed in REST API reference documentation, see at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/globalForwardingRules

> portRange
> string
>
> This field is used along with the target field for TargetHttpProxy,
> TargetHttpsProxy, TargetSslProxy, TargetTcpProxy, TargetVpnGateway,
> TargetPool, TargetInstance.
>
> Applicable only when IPProtocol is TCP, UDP, or SCTP, only packets
> addressed to ports in the specified range will be forwarded to target.
> Forwarding rules with the same [IPAddress, IPProtocol] pair must have
> disjoint port ranges.
>
> Some types of forwarding target have constraints on the acceptable
> ports:
>
> TargetHttpProxy: 80, 8080
>
> TargetHttpsProxy: 443
>
> TargetTcpProxy: 25,
> 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1688, 1883, 5222
>
> TargetSslProxy: 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995,
> 1688, 1883, 5222
>
> TargetVpnGateway: 500, 4500

Comment: yes, got it already. this is a pain :-( anyway thanks for your answer